# Implement a session and retrieve from mysql table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, html

How do I implement this session: (UserID is part of the login table)

```
Session["UserID"]="usrName";
```

Into this code?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login1.Authenticate += Login1_Authenticate;
    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        //database connection string
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=x; Password=x; OPTION=3;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from User where username=? and password=?", cn);

        //Select the username and password from mysql database in login table

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;
        //use asp login control to check username and password
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcCommand("@UserID", 'id.int'));


        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);
        // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
        // If row exists, the login is successful  

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int id = cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value;
        Session["UserID"]="usrName";

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Response.Redirect("UserProfileWall.aspx");
            // Event Authenticate is true forward to user profile
        }

    }
}
```

I need to be able to retrieve the correct UserID when some one inputs there username and password upon login and then some how retrieve it on a new page something like this to retireve it but unsure?

```
string usrName = Convert.ToString(Session["UserID"]);
```

I just dont know how to add the first part, the session into my login code so I can some how store the UserID in my session but also retrieve the correct UserID from the submitted data that takes from my mysql login table.

Comment: no help? Is my question clear enough or understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's dirty, and wrong, but this would work in a pinch I guess.

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)

    {
        var sql = @"SELECT * from Users where userName = ?user and password = ?pass";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        MySqlCommand commandWithParams = new MySqlCommand(sql);

        commandWithParams.Parameters.AddWithValue("?user", Login1.UserName);
        commandWithParams.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pass", Login1.Password);

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("myconn string");

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Open();

        commandWithParams.Connection = conn;


        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(commandWithParams);

        da.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)//I'm sure this has a better way
        {
            Session["userId"] = Convert.ToString(dr["userId"]);
            Session["userName"] = Convert.ToString(dr["userName"]);
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Reponse.Redirect("your_page.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }
```

Here it is again using the Reader method and Odbc.

```
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=x; Password=x; OPTION=3;");
        cn.Open();

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from users where username=? and password=?", cn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = "test";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = "test1";


        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();
            string theUser = (string)dr["userName"];
            string theUserId = Convert.ToString(dr["userId"]);
        }
```

The you can set `theUser` and `theUserId` into session like so:

```
Session.Add("userName", theUser);
Session.Add("userId", theUserId);
```

Comment: This is also 100% untested, and two diff methods I crammed together. So take it for what it's worth for the data extraction. But if this is all your doing for user authentication then I think your doing it wrong.

Comment: Its just asp.nets login authenticate method converted to use mysql rather than mssql, I see no problem with it? Also I think its wrong and im not sure why you use datarow to retrieve the userid.

Comment: I also dont want my method contained in a public int, it has to be done within the code behind

Comment: all you have to do is pass this line in a public variable `string usrName = Convert.ToString(Session["UserID"]);`

Comment: so it doesnt have to be public at all?

Comment: In your crappy example code you are calling dr `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` I'm just following your lead. It needs not be any public or private, it is just an example method and can be put in your code behind with no issue. I use similar in a layered application so this would be called from my codebehind. Just how I do it. FWIW, I  don't care how you do it, fetching users based on username/password combo is still wrong. Sends me the message that you are keeping the password in the clear and not a salted hash.

Comment: Oops, by bad. I read over a line, your not calling DataRow. You can pull out the data how ever you want. I use the datarow method. Seems dirty, but it works esp when I need other values. And it cleans up nice for me.

Comment: password is hashed via mysql and via login_authenticate method. But regardless you failed to understand my question, it was about adding and calling a session to retrieve and store data (userid).

Comment: still tho thats only half my battle?

Comment: But for that matter why not put this logic into a method in codebehind? It's a simple one liner from your login method then `int userId = GetUserId(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);` Then you can do what ever you want with your int, or pass it into session.

Comment: Then pull it from session `string userId = Session("userId").ToString()`

Comment: By the way, sorry for looking down the wrong path, my head got caught up on something else. I think you need to look at the methods the login control offers out of the box http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx

Comment: could u re-edit your post with my code and that int, aslo do I not have to declare the session under the int? so I can mark it correct :)

Comment: i do have this    `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login1.Authenticate += Login1_Authenticate;
    }`

Comment: i thought there was a method like this `cmd.Parameters.Retrieve["UserID"].Value = this.Login1.UserID;` something that would say once you enter username and password it will then figure out which userid that relates to. Then all i have to do is pass that to my session.

Comment: the int doesnt really tell the code that tho so im still stuck

Comment: You need to pull it out of your query, or look at the `OnLoggedIn` event. You can get more data out of the Login control that way too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0hd040.aspx To me it looks like you are trying to fetch the userId value based on user data entry, no other method is doing it for you. So read your data into something like a DataRow, and pull out your values, then cast them as what ever type, and put them in session via `Session("userId") = Convert.ToString(dr["userId"]);`

Comment: Also in your code the hashing never takes place. Your passing raw values to your database. So unless you are storing passwords in the clear you will never read a record and will not be able to set your user specific values into session.

Comment: hey im getting an error about session, it says session does not exist in the current context using your code, also using mysql the way you have forces me to either use 2.0 or 4.0 when I refrence mysql.dll id rather stick with odbc and run the driver for the odbc on my apache.

Comment: Either way with fetching the data, you have to read it into something before you can use it, at least as far as I know. So either method works. Then you can set it to session. Does apache even contain session in the same context as IIS? You can also try the `Session.Add()` method for adding things into session, then read them with `var someValue = Session["someToken"].ToString();`.

Comment: could you use my method with the odbc rather than your own because its very confusing and im getting lost?

Comment: I've updated it with example code using ODBC. I'm still not sure how apache handles session though. I'm on a windows platform only, so I have no problem using the above code.

Comment: At the risk of losing my upvote, and all the hard work here...your ***still*** doing it wrong. Do not store passwords in plain text. I can't stress this enough.

Comment: If I could rewrite it I would just dont know how to. I want to use odbc not store in plain text and store the UserID in a session upon login but its so feckin hard.

Comment: Hard makes it fun. But then again, I'm into that kinda thing. And just because it's hard does not mean you should not do it.